# How to load formated data in gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

For example, I have a source(Id, Name) with some records. I want to bind it to `GridView`. But, I want to format each record before add it to `GridView`, for example, I want to write prefix "test" to all the record where field is "Name". I heared that I need to use `onRowDataBound` event, but I cant understand how.

Comment: check this article - it provides very intuitive example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can do that by capturing the binding event.

```
YourGrid.DataBound += YourGrid_RowDataBound

void YourGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
  {
      e.Row.Cells[1].Text = "test_" + e.Row.Cells[1].Text;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First if you want to make little format on the data you are displaying, you can do this easily  in your `.aspx` using `Eval` function
to search on Google use this [asp.net eval format](https://www.google.com/search?q=asp.net%20eval%20format&aq=1&oq=asp.net%20eval%20&aqs=chrome.2.57j0l2j60j0.6597&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=asp.net%20eval%20format&oq=asp.net%20eval%20format&gs_l=serp.3..0l6j0i30l4.89973.91675.2.92799.3.2.1.0.0.1.220.427.2-2.2.0.les;..0.0...1c.1.4.serp.EaqTm4gyMQ0&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.42965579,d.Yms&fp=1d01c4fbb1e2044b&biw=1024&bih=667)

Second for your example check this question : [Add prefix of http:// or https:// with Eval value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14120430/add-prefix-of-http-or-https-with-eval-value)

Answer (score 0):

Use the DataFormatString in your gridview column. Ex:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="name" DataFormatString="test_{0}" HeaderText="name" 
                    HtmlEncode="False" SortExpression="name" />
```

This will result in:

```
test_YourData
```